# How to remove event listener in my service?

Tags: angular, events, broadcast

I'm new to angular and I want to know how to remove event Listener in my service so it stops receiving any data. I'm currently trying to communicate, where page 1 sends a message to page 2 using broadcast channel. Thanks in advance.`

```js
export class Page2Component implements OnInit {
  private xx : any;
  public person = {} as Person;

  constructor(public broadCastService : BroadcastService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.xx=this.broadCastService.events.subscribe((e) => {
      this.person.age =e.age;
      this.person.name = e.name;
    });
    console.log("onInit");
  
     }
    
  ngOnDestroy() {
    //I tried adding here but it does not remove
    this.broadCastService.channel.removeEventListener("message",this.ngOnDestroy)
    this.xx.unsubscribe();
    console.log("onDestroy");
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="column-6">
 <h2>This is the PAGE 2</h2>
 <p>Message will be display here from first.html</p>

 Name: {{person?.name}}<br>
 Age: {{person?.age}}<br>
<button (click)="ngOnDestroy()">unsubcribe</button><button (click)="ngOnInit()">subcribe</button>
</div>
```

`

```js
export class BroadcastService {
  
  public events: Observable<any>;
  private channel = new BroadcastChannel('test_channel');

  constructor() {
    this.events = new Observable ((observer) =>{
     this.channel.addEventListener ('message', (ev) =>{
       observer.next(ev.data);
     })
     this.channel.onmessageerror = ev => {
       observer.error(ev);
     }
    //I TRIED ADDING removeEventListener here but doesnt work
   });
  }
  public addPerson(person : any) {
    this.channel.postMessage(person); 
  }

  }
```

Comment: So what is not working in code?

Comment: how do i add remove event listener in the code?

Comment: Have you tried removeEventListener() (see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)?

Comment: yes i did , but it doesnt trigger anything

Comment: what is your issue?

Comment: how do i add removeEventListener in the service and how to call it . I added a comment in the code

Comment: try `observer.complete();` (as well).